# React Native Navigator IOS props not being passed through

Tags: ios, react-native, navigator

This is my code for the nav page which picks up all the props from the index page fine. But the nav page has a navigator component and it seems unable to pass through the props from a simple state to the initial route  page in the navigator.

```
var MainPage = React.createClass({
render () {
    return (
        <NavigatorIOS ref="nav" style={styles.container} titleTextColor='#FFFFFF' barTintColor='#061009' tintColor='#ECCB2B' navigationBarHidden={true}
           initialRoute={{
            component:HomePage,
            title: 'Home Page',
            passProps: {
              language:this.props.language
            }
        }} />

    );
}
```

});

I click a button to call a function located on the index page to update the state there and the result will pass through to the home page but not to the initial route navigator page. this.props.language updates on the home page but not on the second page where it is being activated. The value itself is there, its not null, it just never changes.

Functions are passed through ok, its just not updating on the fly. So when I click whilst on the initial route navigator page to change the language, the language changes for the tab bar index page ok but does not update in the initial route navigator page.